# How to graph $y=f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

How to graph $y=f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$?

I have substituted as follows:

$$\begin{cases} y=f(a)=\sin a\\ a=x^2\end{cases}.$$

Then if I graph this with the coordinate axes $y$ and $a$ I get the ordinary sine function. But this doesn't solve my problem. Is it possible to graph my example $f(x^2)$ with the axes $y$ and $x$?

Comment: Why don't graph $g(x)=\sin{x^2}$

Comment: Holding $x=a$ constant doesn't make much sense.  Let $x$ vary, and $x^2$ increases through the nonnegative real numbers.  As $x$ grows, $x^2$ increases more rapidly, so the output $y=\sin(x^2)$ wiggles more rapidly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you trying to graph $f(x^2)$ or $f(x)$ given that $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$? And if the latter (which seems the most likely to me since you wrote $y=f(x^2)$, why did you include that rather than just write $y=\sin(x^2)$?

Comment: @AdamHughes: "Are you trying to graph $f(x^2)$ or $f(x)$ given that $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$?" Well actually I am wondering how both of these two graphs would look like.. I have no idea.

Comment: @user50224 The latter is just the usual graph of $y=\sin x$, the former is going to be a really wacky version of $y=\sin x$ where the waves get really bunched up and close. I recommend looking at software to get a feel for them.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Thanks. Which software would you recommend? Wolfram Alpha does not work. 

I have got another question: Is $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$ and even function? On Wikipedia I found: "Geometrically speaking, the graph face of an even function is symmetric with respect to the y-axis, meaning that its graph remains unchanged after reflection about the y-axis."

Now, I want to test whether this function is even or not. Do I have to plot $f(x)$ or $f(x^2)$?

Comment: WA do know how to plot [$\sin(x^2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x^2%29+for+x+%3D+-5..5).

Comment: You plotted $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ but I wonder how to plot $f(x^2)=sin(x)$.... Is this the same?

Comment: I don't understand what your $f(x^2) = \sin x$ means. A function, say $g$, is something you plug a value in, say $a$, split out another number $b = g(a)$. If you want a plot where the $x$ axis is the value you want to plug in the function, then you are ploting $g(x)$. If you want a plot that you plug $x^2$ into the function $sin(\cdot)$ and plot the result on $y$-axis, then the plot is $y = sin(x^2)$. Description like $f(x^2) = \sin x$ is ill defined because you won't tell you what $f(t)$ is when $t$ is negative. So what is the expression you want to plug in the function $\sin(\cdot)$?

Comment: @achillehui I do neither understand what $f(x^2)=sin(x^2)$ means. That's why I am asking. On this link (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1prb.pdf) in example 1A-3e I saw the following: "Identify each of the following as even, odd , or neither:""$J_{0}(x^2)$, where $J_{0}(x)$ is a function you never heard of"
Now I am wondering what $J_{0}(x^2)$ looks like, so I have taken the example $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$...

Comment: That exercise doesn't say anything about $f(x^2) = \sin(x^2)$ or anything like that. You should forget what you believe first. Instead, you should think like this. 

You have two blackbox $F$ and $G$. If you plug a value $x$ into blackbox $F$, it return $\sin x$. If you plug $x$ into blackbox $G$, it return $x^2$. If you connect output of $G$ to input of $F$, then when you plug $x$ into the input of $G$, the output of $F$ will return a value $\sin x^2$. 
(to be cont'd)

Comment: If you express this in terms of functions, this becomes $f(g(x)) = \sin x^2$. Since there isn't a special name for the function associated with $G$ which send $x$ to $x^2$, we simply use the notation $f(x^2)$ as a shorthand for the function corresponds to the chain of operations $x \mapsto x^2 \mapsto \sin x^2$.

In this spirit, the $f(\cdot)$ in $f(x^2) = \sin(x^2)$ is really the $\sin(\cdot)$ function. When you plot $f(x^2)$, you are not plotting $\sin(\cdot)$ but the function corresponds to the chain of operations.

Comment: Finally, I understand it. Thanks! I am sorry for only being able to give you the upvotes for your comments. You should have got more for your perfect help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, you can create the graph of $y=g(f(x))$ from them easily in the following manner.

First, draw the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ on the same set of axes, and additionally draw the line $y=x$ there as well.

To plot the point $(x,g(f(x)))$, start at the point $(x,0)$ on the horizontal axis. Then move vertically to the graph of $f$. You are now at the point $(x,f(x))$.

Move horizontally to the line $y=x$. You are now at the point $(f(x),f(x))$.

Move vertically to the graph of $g$. You are now at the point $(f(x),g(f(x)))$.

Move horizontally until you are directly over the starting point. You are now at the desired point $(x,g(f(x)))$ on the graph of $g\circ f$.

This is a standard trick that lets you evaluate any number of functions successively. If you need to find $f_n(\cdots f_3(f_2(f_1(x)))\cdots)$, start at $(x,0)$, then move up to $f_1$, over to the diagonal, up to $f_2$, over to the diagonal, up to $f_3$, over to the diagonal, etc. . It is especially useful when iterating a single function over and over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nevertheless, I have some more questions. It would be very helpful if you could answer them:  
1. With your method I graph $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$, right?  
2. In my case $f(x)$ is $x^2$ and $g(x)$ is $\sin(x)$?
3. Another way of writing this would be: $$a(x)=f(x^2)=sin(x^2)=g(h(x))$$ with $g(x)=\sin x$ and $h(x)=x^2$?  
4. $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$ is an even function???

Are my 4 statements correct? A short answer would help a lot.

Comment: Your statements (1) and (3) seem incorrect and appear to confuse the notation. Your statement (2), using the notation of $f$ and $g$ in my answer, is correct. Your statement (4) is again confused. The function described as "$p(x) = \sin(x^2)$" is indeed an even function of $x$. That means precisely that $p(-x)$ and $p(x)$ are identical for all $x$. You can see this by computing directly that $(-x)^2=x^2$, so apply the sine to both sides to get $\sin((-x)^2) = \sin(x^2)$, that is, $p(-x) = p(x)$.

Comment: Ok, let me put it differently. I am working on these exercises http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1prb.pdf . I don't understand 1A-3e. "Identify each of the following as even, odd , or neither:""$J_{0}(x^2)$, where $J_{0}(x)$ is a function you never heard of"
Now I am wondering what $J_{0}(x^2)$ looks like, so I have taken the example $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$...

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, my problem looks like: You got any $f(x)$. 1. **What is then $f(x^2)$?** 2. **How to graph this $f(x^2)$ on a coordinate system with x- and y-axes???** Then, as soon as I can imagine the graph, I can decide if it is even or not...

Comment: The argument I presented above shows that the function $f(x)=J_0(x^2)$ is even because you get the same result out regardless of whether you put in $x$ or $-x$, right? You should think of this as a composition of two successive functions: first, the squaring function (call it $s$); then, the function $J_0$. Their composition is $f(x) = (J_0\circ s)(x) = J_0(s(x))$. $s$ is even, so any function applied to $s$ is even.

Comment: The method of my answer tells you *exactly* how to graph this. You are graphing $y = f(s(x))$, where $x$ is the independent variable and $s$ is the squaring function. The graph of $s$ is an ordinary parabola, and the graph of $f$ is whatever. Whether you start at $(x,0)$ or $(-x,0)$, you end up at the same height. So the function is even. Visually, this means it is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. **Just try my method and you will see it.** It should be perfectly clear if you just **do** it.

Comment: Finally, I understand it. Thanks! I am sorry for only being able to give you the upvotes for your comments. You should have got more for your perfect help.
One final question. In this exercise (1A-3e) the graph looks like $y=f(x)=sin(x^2)$, right (if I assume $J_{0}(x)=\sin (x)$)? If this is true, then I think I got it. (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3Dsin%28x^2%29)

Comment: Yes, that's right. And thanks for the upvotes.